# Squid, ERROR: Negotiate Authentication validating user

Tags: squid, kerberos

Настраиваю Squid через kerberos авторизацию. При попытке пользователя авторизоваться на прокси через браузер, в cache.log такой текст:

```html
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(487): pid=10851 :2018/07/11 08:46:25| negotiate_kerberos_auth: INFO: Starting version 3.0.4sq
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(546): pid=10851 :2018/07/11 08:46:25| negotiate_kerberos_auth: INFO: Setting keytab to /etc/squid/proxy.keytab
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(570): pid=10851 :2018/07/11 08:46:25| negotiate_kerberos_auth: INFO: Changed keytab to MEMORY:negotiate_kerberos_auth_10851
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(610): pid=10258 :2018/07/11 08:32:06| negotiate_kerberos_auth: DEBUG: Got 'YR TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGA4AlAAAADw==' from squid (length: 59).
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(663): pid=10258 :2018/07/11 08:32:06| negotiate_kerberos_auth: DEBUG: Decode 'TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGA4AlAAAADw==' (decoded length: 40).
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(673): pid=10258 :2018/07/11 08:32:06| negotiate_kerberos_auth: WARNING: received type 1 NTLM token
2018/07/11 08:32:06 kid1| ERROR: Negotiate Authentication validating user. Result: {result=BH, notes={message: received type 1 NTLM token; }}
```

kpass настраивал так:

```html
ktpass -princ HTTP/proxy1.spz.int@SPZ.INT -mapuser squidproxy@spz.int -crypto RC4-HMAC-NT -pass passW0rd -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out C:\proxy.keytab
```

============= squid.conf ========================

```html
auth_param negotiate program /usr/lib64/squid/negotiate_kerberos_auth -d -i -s HTTP/proxy1.spz.int@SPZ.INT
auth_param negotiate children 10
auth_param negotiate keep_alive on
acl auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
```

============= /etc/krb5.conf ==========================

```html
# Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = SPZ.INT
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
 default_keytab_name = /etc/squid/proxy.keytab

[realms]
 SPZ.INT = {
  kdc = spz.int
 }

[domain_realm]
 .spz.int = SPZ.INT
 spz.int = SPZ.INT
```

====================================================

Через kinit, авторизация проходит:

**kinit -V -k -t /etc/squid/squidproxy.keytab HTTP/proxy1.spz.int@SPZ.INT**

Using default cache: persistent:0:0
Using principal: HTTP/proxy1.spz.int@SPZ.INT
Using keytab: /etc/squid/proxy.keytab
Authenticated to Kerberos v5

**klist**

Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: HTTP/proxy1.spz.int@SPZ.INT

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07/11/2018 08:59:23  07/11/2018 18:59:23  krbtgt/SPZ.INT@SPZ.INT
    renew until 07/18/2018 08:59:23

Comment: Основная ошибка тут: `negotiate_kerberos_auth: WARNING: received type 1 NTLM token`. Ваш браузер (или чем вы ходите на прокси) "пихает" в сквид NTLM token. Т.е. по факты не пытается аутентифицироваться билетом kerberos. Для начала дэбага со стороны клиента (например, windows 7) надо посмотреть список билетов (tickets), которые выдал контроллер домена: команда `klist`. Среди списка билетов должно быть что-то типа такого: `HTTP/proxy1.spz.int@SPZ.INT` после того, как вы сделали попытку открыть сайт в браузере.

Comment: Второй момент - настройка прокси в браузере. Kerboros очень чувствителен к именам. Т.е. в настройках прокси (в браузере) необходимо указывать имя прокси (proxy1.spz.int), а не скажем ip-адрес. Третье. Я не уверен, что когда вы мапили принципал нэйм к юзеру в АД, то указали правильный шифр (-crypto RC4-HMAC-NT). Возможно придется использовать другой...

Comment: Да, ошибка была в настройке адреса прокси в браузере: вместо имени был ip-адрес. Спасибо!
Вопрос ещё такой сразу: правильно понимаю, что например Линуксовые клиенты прокси сервера не смогут использовать kerberos и для них придётся настраивать ntlm?

Comment: Линукс уже давно "дружит" с контроллерами AD. Поэтому сделать можно и керберос. Другое дело, что надо будет повозиться с настройками Samba, winbind и kerberos на линуксе. Более простого решения не знаю.